# How are Kubernetes persistent volumes related to AzureDisks in AKS?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

Say I have One K8s node with Two pods. Each pod claims 5Gi of PV storage. The provisioned AKS VM (node) has a 32GiB SKU SSD AzureDisk data drive.

Will/can both of the 5Gi K8s volumes be located on the same AzureDisk?

If one AzureDisk is required per K8s volume, why would you claim anything but the AzureDisk SKU storage size for a pod (assuming you target only Azure)?

If one AzureDisk can be shared between multiple K8s volumes, then how do you map the paths for two pods to different AzureDisk paths? Or do they get separate partitions?

Can you move a K8s volume to another AzureDisk if you provision a bigger one?

The thing is I have many pods that need PV, but they only need a small amount. Much less than the smallest SKU (4GB SSD, 32GB HDD). I guess one option would be to co-locate all containers in one Pod, but that just doesn't seem right either ...

Comment: Can you add more information about your cluster - version, how many nodes it has? From your question it seems you want to use [local volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local). Why you don't use [azureDisk volume type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#azuredisk)?

Comment: Hello @maloo. Any updates?